# I can’t login to the admin panel in production

Tags: amazon-ec2, strapi

On my production server, now when anyone tries to sign into the admin panel it gets stuck on the loading spinning wheel. The console outputs this:

```
Admin-AuthenticatedApp.5f479702.chunk.js:24 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading ‘digest’)
at Object.digestMessage (Admin-AuthenticatedApp.5f479702.chunk.js:24:4912)
at Tt (Admin-AuthenticatedApp.5f479702.chunk.js:24:4992)
at Admin-AuthenticatedApp.5f479702.chunk.js:24:7064
at Admin-AuthenticatedApp.5f479702.chunk.js:24:7076
at Ll (main.c0d82de4.js:6754:25634)
at Oi (main.c0d82de4.js:6754:44744)
at main.c0d82de4.js:6754:42937
at A (main.c0d82de4.js:6833:1597)
at MessagePort.le (main.c0d82de4.js:6833:1966)
```

What I tried:

- Deleting .cache, dist, node_modules & package-lock.json. Reinstalling
  npm packages and rebuilding.
- Deleting all admin users from the
  database. Then I was prompted to create a new user account, but once
  I did the same problem happens.
- I also tried to completely drop and let Strapi rebuild the database, and the same issue happens.

It was working fine until today when I pulled in an update to the repository which bumped the Strapi version from 4.12.1 to 4.12.6. Just this and a schema change. And it is all working normally on my local machine.

Any ideas? I’m not sure what to do at this stage.

System Information
Strapi Version: 4.12.6
Operating System: Ubuntu. AWS EC2
Database: MySQL
Node Version: 18.17.0
NPM Version: 9.6.7
Yarn Version: